# Перевод строки в десятичное число. Java

Tags: java

Есть такие строки:

```
0x16
012
0b10
62
```

Нужно перевести их в:

```
22
10
2
62
```

соответственно, но при использовании `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` получаю `NumberFormatException`, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: @pavlofff, не совсем.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

например, можно написать такую функцию

```
private static int StringToInteger(String input)
    {
        if(input.startsWith("0x"))
        {   
            return Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2), 16);
        }
        else if(input.startsWith("0b"))
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2), 2);
        }
        else if(input.startsWith("0") && input.length() > 1)
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(input.substring(1), 8);
        }
        else
        {
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю за пример! Теперь намного лучше понимаю работу parseInt метода.

Answer (score 5):

В метод `Integer.parseInt(String, int)` передается строка, содержащая число в той или иной системе счисления **без каких-либо префиксов**:

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("16", 16));  // 22
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("12", 8));   // 10
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("10", 2));   // 2
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("62", 10));  // 62
```